# Render a widget from a separate file?

Tags: flutter

In my app I want a bottom nav bar widget in my different pages.

Here is basically what my pages look like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
    Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  var pages = ['home', 'search', 'profile'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _onItemTapped(int index) { 
      String page = pages[index];
      context.go('/$page');
    }

    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
                child:const Text("Home page",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
            ),  
        ),  

        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(  
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[  
            BottomNavigationBarItem(  
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),  
              label: 'Home',  
              backgroundColor: Colors.green  
            ),  
            BottomNavigationBarItem(  
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),  
              label: 'Search',  
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow  
            ),  
            BottomNavigationBarItem(  
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),  
              label: 'Profile',  
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,  
            ),  
          ],  
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,  
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,  
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,  
          iconSize: 40,  
          onTap: _onItemTapped,  
          elevation: 5   
        ),
    );  
  }
}
```

Copying the bottom nav bar widget code in each page is not very DRY. Is there any way to rendered the bottom nav bar widget from a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separated widget file:

name it `bar.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final int selectedIndex;
  final Function callbackFunction;

  const BottomBar(
      {Key? key, this.selectedIndex = 0, required this.callbackFunction})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
              backgroundColor: Colors.green),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Search',
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        currentIndex: widget.selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        iconSize: 40,
        onTap: (int index) {
          widget.callbackFunction(index);
        },
        elevation: 5);
  }
}
```

The implementation:

```
import 'bar.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  void callbackFunction(int index) {
    //
    print('You tapped button $index');
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Main Page'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(
        callbackFunction: callbackFunction,
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create List with your pages...

```
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
        Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
        @override
        _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }
    
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
      List<Widget> pages = [homeWidgetPage, searchWidgetPage, profileWidgetPage];
     void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    
        return Scaffold(
            body: pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
  
    
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(  
              items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[  
                BottomNavigationBarItem(  
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),  
                  label: 'Home',  
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green  
                ),  
                BottomNavigationBarItem(  
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),  
                  label: 'Search',  
                  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow  
                ),  
                BottomNavigationBarItem(  
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),  
                  label: 'Profile',  
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,  
                ),  
              ],  
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,  
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,  
              selectedItemColor: Colors.black,  
              iconSize: 40,  
              onTap: _onItemTapped,  
              elevation: 5   
            ),
        );  
      }
    }
```

Comment: The requirement is to separate the bottom navigation bar in a separate file.

Comment: It is a separate file, create a file as I am saying and other files for each page that do you want.